# Как сделать сортировку товаров в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Вопрос очень распространенный, но тем не менее, испробовав кучу вариантов из гугла, нужного результата добиться не удалось.

Перед списком товаров располагается верхняя панель, куда нужно добавить сортировку по цене и популярности (туда и обратно). Плюс рядом нужно поместить выбор количества отображаемых товаров на странице (к примеру, по 20, 30 и т.д.).

Нюанс 1: Обе сортировки должны быть помещены в select или какой-нибудь dropdown.

Нюанс 2: Было бы здорово, если бы выбранные параметры сортировок сохранялись.

Быть может кто-то недавно решал подобную задачу и сохранились какие-то наработки.

Спасибо за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Задача делится на 2 части.

1) Отображение настроек сортировки и фильтрации. Если у Вас используется комплексный компонент catalog, то в нём пишите всю логику по выводу и по обработке.

```
<?
$sort_arr = array(
    "По цене (по возрастанию)" => array("sort"=>"price", "order"=>"asc"),
    "По цене (по убыванию)" => array("sort"=>"price", "order"=>"desc"),
    "По популярности" => array("sort"=>"show", "order"=>"asc"),
);
$default_sort = array("sort"=>"price", "order"=>"asc");
$sort = "";
$order = "";
foreach($sort_arr as $sort_data)
    if($sort_data["sort"] == $_REQUEST["sort"] && $sort_data["order"] == $_REQUEST["order"])){
        $sort = $_REQUEST["sort"];
        $order = $_REQUEST["order"];
    }
if($sort == ""){
    $sort = $default_sort["sort"];
    $order = $default_sort["order"];
}?>
<select onchenge="window.location = this.value;">
<?foreach($sort_arr as $sort_option):?>
    <option value="<?=$APPLICATION->GetCurPageParam("sort={$sort_option["sort"]}&order={$sort_option["order"]}", array("sort", "order")?>" <?=($sort_option["sort"] == $sort && $sort_option["order"] == $order)?"selected='selected'":"";?>></option>
<?endforeach;?>
</select>
```

2) Подстановка нужных значений в компонент

```
    <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog.section",
    "",
    Array(
        ...
        "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => $sort,
        "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => $order,
        "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
        ...
    ),
);?>
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, куда здесь подставить CATALOG_PRICE_1?

Comment: @MikhailA. в массив значений `$sort_arr` ключ `sort`